# Wrong ordering of the categoryAxis labels of kendo ui graph only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo graph to display a line chart. The issue I am facing is that the labels of the categoryAxis(x-axis) are not appearing in proper order only in the chrome browser(Working fine in all other browsers).

This is the graph in Firefox, the labels are in proper format
[image: Graph in Firefox(perfectly okay)]

This is the graph in Google Chrome, the labels are not in proper format
[image: Graph in Chrome(label ordering are wrong)]

The data source I am using is a local data(array). So the ordering of the data is in proper format in the array.

[This is the Snippet example, run in two different browsers to know the difference](https://dojo.telerik.com/eREVEF/3)

Just curious to know that the reason behind the issue

Answer (score 1):

Chrome probably use different approach when suming/substracting mixed types:

```
console.log([2019,2020,2018,"Due"].sort((a,b) => a-b))
```

This will give you different results in Chrome and Firefox. I dont know what compare function kendo use, but its probably related to this behaviour and could be reported as issue.

As workaround, just add custom compare to your config (this example will push any string before numbers):

```
dataBound: function(e) {
  var axis = e.sender.options.categoryAxis;
  axis.categories = axis.categories.sort(function(a,b) { 
    if (typeof a !== typeof b) {
      return (typeof a === 'string' ? -1 : 1);
    }
    return a-b;
  });
}
```